# Include in a property with Generic Type in a sub property

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I need to make an include.
I have the following classes

```
public class TestRoot
{
    public int TestRootId { get; set; }
    public TestBase TestBase { get; set; }
}

public abstract class TestBase
{
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class TestA : TestBase
{
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class TestB : TestBase
{
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do this includes?
I tried it in a few ways but it doesn't work.

```
context.TestRoot.Include(i => i.TestBase)
                .Include(i => i.TestBase.User)
                .Include(i => i.TestBase.Item)
                .Include(i => i.TestBase.Address)
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.TestRootId == 1)

context.TestRoot.Include(i => i.TestBase)
                .Include(i => i.TestBase.User)
                .Include(i => (i.TestBase as TestA).Item) // Error
                .Include(i => (i.TestBase as TestA).Address) // Error
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.TestRootId == 1)

context.TestRoot.Include(i => i.TestBase)
                .Include(i => i.TestBase.User)
                .Include("TestBase.Item") // Error
                .Include("TestBase.Address") // Error
                .FirstOrDefaultAsync(f => f.TestRootId == 1)
```

Error:
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'TestBase' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Item'

Comment: Could you post the whole dbcontext class, pls?

Comment: Maybe this would be helpful? [Inheritance Strategy in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/inheritance-strategy-in-code-first.aspx) BTW, there are no generic types in the code you posted.

Comment: The problem is not in the context, the records are saved correctly. The problem is when trying to perform an Include of a sub property that can be a class (TestA) or another class (TestB). It is of the TPT type.